# Python can't authenticate with ntlm

Tags: python, http, authentication, urllib2, ntlm

I am trying to parse a site on my intranet and when authenticating as below I get an error saying that authentication is required, which I have already done. Why am I still getting this 401 error?

Thanks in advance!

> File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
>   raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
>   urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Authorization Required

```
import urllib2
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler

user = r'domain\myuser'
password = 'mypasswd'
url = 'http://myinternal.homepage'

passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
# create the NTLM authentication handler
auth_NTLM = HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman)

# create and install the opener
opener = urllib2.build_opener(auth_NTLM)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)

# retrieve the result
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print(response)
```

Comment: Try the latest http://code.google.com/p/python-ntlm/ and http://stackoverflow.com/a/14904367/819417

Answer (score 1):

Try not putthing the 'r' in front of 'domain\myuser'. I have used this without the 'r' and it works for me. One thing that helped me- ( i'm guessing you probably already did . . . just in case though) check the headers that the url returns to you. I did this with Mechanize http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/ and based of the headers returned figured out I should be using NTLM auth ( as seen here). I also have a similar question [How to 'convert' variable of type instance such that the variable can be used to authenticate when making system calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026430/how-to-convert-variable-of-type-instance-such-that-the-variable-can-be-used-to).